# Inserting an element after another with .after() does not fully work

Tags: javascript, html

In a webpage (from remote server where I have no access) I want to insert the page URL after a certain element, and after the webpage loads.

**My solution is posted in the snippet below**

```js
var address = document.URL;
var pane = document.getElementsByClassName("heading--large")[0];
pane.after("<a href=\"" + address + "\">" + address + "</a>");
```

The page's **URL** is inserted, but only as text, not as a recognized element.

The URL is NOT active like the other links. Take a look at the snapshot I uploaded.

[image: SnapShot]

Why is the text in my anchor-element not rendering blue? Furthermore the "href" is not highlighted red like the other anchor elements are below.

Is ".after()" not the suitable function?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are inserting a string after the `pane` node as the [`Element.after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) documentation shows. If you want to use `after`, modify your code with [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and modify the resulting elements to mirror your original intent

```js
var address =
  "https://www.ghacks.net/2021/10/02/which-are-the-best-screenshot-extensions-for-chrome/";
var pane = document.getElementsByClassName("heading--large")[0];
var myLink = document.createElement("a");
myLink.href = address;
myLink.textContent = address;
pane.after(myLink);
```

```html
<main class="post-list mt--60 mt--first--0">
  <h1 class="heading--large" style="color:#43414e;font-weight:400;"> Which are the best screenshot extensions for Chrome? </h1>
  <div class="text-small ghacks-links ghacks-links--smallunderline mt--10 mb--20" style="font-size: 14px;opacity:0.9;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:20px;"> by Shaun on October 02, 2021 in Google Chrome extensions - Last Update: September 30, 2021 - 6 comments </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.after()` places nodes after a given element. A node is many things, but there's two types of nodes we usually are concerned with are elements and text. Your requirements are:

1. Create an `<a>`
2. Add `href` attribute with a pre-determined value to `<a>`<sup>*</sup>
3. Add pre-determined text content to `<a>`<sup>*</sup>
4. Place `<a>` after `.heading--large`<sup>*</sup>

   <sup>*</sup><sup>#2, #3, and #4 can be in any order</sup>

`.after()` can only do #4, so here's a possibility if you really want to use `.after()`:

1. `const A = document.createElement('a')`
2. `A.href = address`
3. `A.textContent = address`
4. `pane.after(A)`

```js
const address = document.URL;
// This a modern equivalent
const pane = document.querySelector(".heading--large");
/*
This will safely render htmlString at a specfic location in relation to a given element.
*/
pane.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", `<a href="${address}">${address}</a>`);

// Check to see if it's correct with .outerHTML property
console.log(document.querySelector("header").outerHTML);
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class='heading--large'>Chrome Extensions</h1>
</header>
```